# Projeto python e tkinter menu

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, menu, tkinter, syntax-error

Bom meu projetinho com python e a biblioteca tkinter esse , eu estou tentando fazer um sistema de cadastro mas sou um pouco novo nessa parte de orientação a objetos em python, e acho que esse é a parte que esta me dando erro!
Poderiam me dar uma ajuda do que fazer:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import tkinter.messagebox        

#-*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
import sys

class novo:
    ## Classe oonde forma a primeira janela com os menus
    def __init__(self, janela):
        # Inicia como None

        janela.title("Sapataria do Seu IVO - Menu Inicial")

        self.b1=Button(janela, text='Cadastrar Tenis', command=self.new_janCT)
        self.b1.place(x=335, y=245)

        self.b2=Button(janela, text='Relatório Geral', command=self.new_janRG)
        self.b2.place(x=335, y=285)

        self.b3=Button(janela, text='Realizar Venda', command=self.new_janRV)
        self.b3.place(x=335, y=325)

        self.b4=Button(janela, text='Atualizar preços', command=self.new_janAP)
        self.b4.place(x=335, y=365)

        self.b5=Button(janela, text='Cadastrar Cores', command=self.new_janCC)
        self.b5.place(x=335, y=405)

        self.b6=Button(janela, text='Guarda no TXT', command=self.new_janGT)
        self.b6.place(x=335, y=445)

        self.b7=Button(janela, text='Recupera do TXT', command=self.new_janRT)
        self.b7.place(x=335, y=485)

        self.b8=Button(janela, text='Sair', command=root.destroy)
        self.b8.place(x=335, y=525)

        self.l1=Label(janela, text='raiz!')
        self.l1.place(x=750, y=560)

        screen_width = janela.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = janela.winfo_screenheight()

        width = 800
        height = 600

        x = (screen_width/2)-(width/2)
        y = (screen_height/2)-(height/2)

        self.jan = None
        self.caixa=Frame(janela)
        self.caixa.grid()

########################################################################################

    def new_janCT(self):
        def inserindoDados(self, *args):
            self.listbox.insert(END, self.inserir.get())

        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Cadastro de tenis')
            self.l.grid()

            self.lblistbox = Label(self.jan, text="ESTOQUE DO TIO IVO", bg='lightSteelBlue3', fg='blue').place(x=50, y=60)

            self.listbox = Listbox(self.jan, width=60)
            self.listbox.insert(0,"Criando listbox = 1")

            self.listbox.place(x=100, y=200)

            self.lblistbox1 = Label(self.jan, text="Inserindo dados", bg='lightSteelBlue3', fg='blue').place(x=20, y=10)
            self.inserir = StringVar()
            self.txtlistbox = Entry(self.jan, textvariable=self.inserir, width=47).place(x=120, y=10)
            self.btninserir = Button(self.jan, text='INSERIR',height=1, width=10, command=self.inserindoDados).place(x=325, y=30)

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()

#########################################################################################

    def new_janRG(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Relatório Geral')
            self.l.grid()

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()

#########################################################################################

    def new_janRV(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Realizar Venda')
            self.l.grid()

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()


#########################################################################################

    def new_janAP(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Atualizar preços')
            self.l.grid()

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()


#########################################################################################

    def new_janCC(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Cadastrar Cores')
            self.l.grid()

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()


#########################################################################################

    def new_janGT(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Guarda no TXT')
            self.l.grid()

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()


#########################################################################################

    def new_janRT(self):
        # Verifica se já foi criada
        if self.jan is None:
            self.jan=Tk()
            self.jan.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.fecha_jan)

            self.l=Label(self.jan, text='Recupera do TXT')
            self.l.grid()

            self.jan.geometry('800x600')
        else:
            # Se já foi, basta colocá-la na frente
            self.jan.lift()

#########################################################################################            



    def new_janSA(self):
        #self.janela.destroy()
        sys.exit()
        l1.text['Para Fechar clique no X vermelho acima! ']


#########################################################################################            

    def fecha_jan(self):
        # Seta de novo em None para recriar quando abrir
        self.jan.destroy()
        self.jan = None

root=Tk()

novo(root)
root.geometry('800x600')

root.mainloop()
novo()
```

#### Erro

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ecaet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

File "G:\python\Tkinter\main.py", line 110, in new_janCT
    self.btninserir = Button(self.jan, text='INSERIR',height=1, width=10, command=self.inserindoDados).place(x=325, y=30)

AttributeError: 'novo' object has no attribute 'inserindoDados'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem o objetivo, mas o problema se dá pela forma que o `inserindoDados` é referenciado. você pode retirar o `inserindoDados` do escopo do `new_janCT` ou  retirar o self no command `command=inserindoDados`, mas isso acarretaría em outro erro, então sugiro retirar o `inserindoDados` do escopo.

```
def inserindoDados(self, *args):
    self.listbox.insert(END, self.inserir.get())
def new_janCT(self):
    # restante do código sem o inserindoDados
```

Answer (score 0):

A causa do erro é você não ter referenciado o `inserirDados`. O que você criou não foi um método da classe `novo` e sim uma função dentro do método `new_janCT`. Para resolver este problema, basta você trocar `self.inserindoDados` por apenas `inserindoDados`.

Agora lembre-se que você não poderá chamar a função `inserindoDados` em outras partes do seu código, pois ela só existe dentro do método `new_janCT`. Se você quiser chamá-la dentro de outros métodos você deverá instanciar ela primeiro.

Você pode fazer isso trocando o escopo que você cria o `inserindoDados`:

```
# Se você trocar o escopo, deverá usar o "self" quando for chamar o método sempre.
def inserindoDados(self, *args):
    self.listbox.insert(END, self.inserir.get())
def new_janCT(self):
    # Restante do código...
```

ou então colocando este código:

```
# Dentro do método new_janCT
self.inserindoDados = inserindoDados
```